# Public array from an userform to module is empty, but inside the userform it get the values

Tags: arrays, vba, module, public, userform

I'm running into an odd issue.  I have 2 `Userform`, at first `Userform2` was inside `Userform1`, but I wasn't able to make it run. After that I made that a Sub in my Module call `Userform2` after other once `Userform1` is done.

The problem is the `Userform2` is a Multiselect `Listbox`, and I save each selection in an array and when the Userform2 unloads the array seems to be empty.

I have checked for hours many errors like: I have no explicit option on, but the code is pretty short and I have looked for the array within my code and it only appears on the exact parts I wanted it to be.

Neither the public array as variant was a problem, because it is outside the Userform and in the original Module.

I'm from Chile so some variables have names in Spanish and my English might not be so good, I'll do my best to explain my self.

Here is the code:

```
 Global lenarrv
 Global Arrver
 Global BoxPMData
 Global anno
 Global PMDATAarray
 Global LenPMDArray
 Public varfamilia As Variant
 Public pampm As Variant



  Sub AbrirMaestro(ByVal anno As Variant)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False



  UserForm1.Show
  UserForm2.Show

  Dim Arrver() As Variant
  Dim lenarrv As Long

  contentosrcontento = 1
  lenarrv = UBound(pampm)
  For tt = 0 To lenarrv - 1
     ReDim Arrver(contentosrcontento)
     Arrver(contentosrcontento) = pampm(tt)
     contentosrcontento = contentosrcontento + 1
  Next tt

  lenarrv = UBound(Arrver)

  Inputbox_PMDATA anno
  End Sub
```

Here comes the Userforms:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     Me.StartUpPosition = 1
     Me.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - Me.Width - 400
 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim listaitems As Variant
 Workbooks("MAESTROS.xlsx").Activate
 numerofilas = Workbooks("MAESTROS.xlsx").Sheets("VERTICALES").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
 listaitems = Workbooks("MAESTROS.xlsx").Sheets("VERTICALES").Range("A2:A" & numerofilas)

 listaitems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(listaitems)

     For h = 1 To numerofilas - 1
         ListBox1.AddItem listaitems(h)
     Next h
 Workbooks("MAESTROS.xlsx").Close False

 End Sub


 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim count As Integer



 count = 1
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
     If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
             ReDim pampm(count)
             pampm(i) = ListBox1.List(i)
             count = count + 1
     End If
 Next i


 Unload UserForm2

 End Sub
```

Here is `UserForm1` :

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     Me.StartUpPosition = 1
     Me.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - Me.Width - 400
 End Sub
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim ListItems As Variant
 MsgBox ("Elegir el archivo MAESTRO")
 Master = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=False)

 isBool = VarType(Master) = vbBoolean
 If isBool Then If Not Master Then End

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set abrirlibro = Workbooks.Open(Master)
 numrows = abrirlibro.Worksheets("MASTERFAMILIA").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
 ListItems = abrirlibro.Worksheets("MASTERFAMILIA").Range("B2:B" & numrows)

 ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
         For i = 1 To numrows - 1
             ComboBox1.AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
         Next i
 'abrirlibro.Close False
 'Set abrirlibro = Nothing
 End Sub

 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 varfamilia = ComboBox1.value
 Unload UserForm1

 End Sub
```

I can't past the full code since there are more than 2k lines..

Any help is welcome.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change

```
Public pampm As Variant
```

to

```
Public pampm() As Variant
```

and

```
ReDim pampm(count)
```

to

```
ReDim Preserve pampm(count)
```

Comment: I tried that already, but sadly I get the error "Type mismatch (Error 13)"  even if I add the `as Variant` after the `pamp(count)`

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you, Omg that was so naive from me